# rolling median stiil leave one NaN value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    3348    3349    3350    3351    3352    3353    3354    3355    3356    3357    ... 40287   40288   40289   40290   40291   40292   40293   40294   40295   40296
U1  231.7   232.4   232.1   232.1   214 232.3   218.5   217.3   231.7   217.1   ... 223.9   231.5   222.8   234.6   230.7   230.8   227.3   232.3   229.4   NaN
U2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 221.2   227.2   218.8   234.6   227 232.2   230.5   232.1   233.7   226.1
U3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 225.3   228.3   223.1   234.5   227 233.6   231 234.2   233.4   225.8
U4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 225.2   230.6   NaN 235.5   228.3   232.4   230.6   231.1   230.5   227.3
U5  230.3   231.4   230.4   230.4   220.4   232.8   219 217.9   230.2   220.4   ... 224.9   228.9   223.7   231.9   227.1   232.4   231.5   231.1   230 225.9
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
U92 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 229.3   235.3   227.3   230.8   234 231.6   228.5   229.5   227.3   234.6
U93 238.8   238.3   239.2   239.4   227.3   238.9   239.3   232.2   238.6   227.7   ... NaN 237.5   229 237.1   NaN 232.1   223.2   NaN 227.9   235.1
U94 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 231.9   236 232.9   238.3   234.4   NaN 232.9   230.9   229 234.5
U95 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 233.9   237.5   233.6   236.6   NaN 235.2   234.8   236.6   230 235.5
U96 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

There are several NaN values and I did a data cleaning using pandas's rolling() method as follows:

```
X = X.fillna(X.rolling(12, min_periods=1).median())
```

I want to replace the NaN with a rolling median of window size `12` and at least `1` valid values should be present in the window.

Ans the result is :

```
3348    3349    3350    3351    3352    3353    3354    3355    3356    3357    ... 40287   40288   40289   40290   40291   40292   40293   40294   40295   40296
U1  231.7   232.4   232.1   232.1   214 232.3   218.5   217.3   231.7   217.1   ... 223.9   231.5   222.8   234.6   230.7   230.8   227.3   232.3   229.4   NaN
U2  231.7   232.4   232.1   232.1   214 232.3   218.5   217.3   231.7   217.1   ... 221.2   227.2   218.8   234.6   227 232.2   230.5   232.1   233.7   226.1
U3  231.7   232.4   232.1   232.1   214 232.3   218.5   217.3   231.7   217.1   ... 225.3   228.3   223.1   234.5   227 233.6   231 234.2   233.4   225.8
U4  231.7   232.4   232.1   232.1   214 232.3   218.5   217.3   231.7   217.1   ... 225.2   230.6   222.8   235.5   228.3   232.4   230.6   231.1   230.5   227.3
U5  230.3   231.4   230.4   230.4   220.4   232.8   219 217.9   230.2   220.4   ... 224.9   228.9   223.7   231.9   227.1   232.4   231.5   231.1   230 225.9
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
U92 237.1   237.3   237.4   237.5   231.3   238.9   240.2   230.5   237 236.1   ... 229.3   235.3   227.3   230.8   234 231.6   228.5   229.5   227.3   234.6
U93 238.8   238.3   239.2   239.4   227.3   238.9   239.3   232.2   238.6   227.7   ... 228.3   237.5   229 237.1   234 232.1   223.2   231.65  227.9   235.1
U94 237.95  237.8   238.3   238.45  229.3   238.9   239.75  231.35  237.8   231.9   ... 231.9   236 232.9   238.3   234.4   232.1   232.9   230.9   229 234.5
U95 238.8   238.3   239.2   239.4   227.3   238.9   239.3   232.2   238.6   227.7   ... 233.9   237.5   233.6   236.6   234.3   235.2   234.8   236.6   230 235.5
U96 238.8   238.3   239.2   239.4   227.3   238.9   239.3   232.2   238.6   227.7   ... 231.05  236.5   230.9   236.6   234.3   232.1   229.4   231.35  228.8   234.7
```

As can be seen that all NaNs are replached by a moving median of window size 12. But there is still one NaN at the top right corner. It seems that this specific NaN is always there, whatever I tune the `window_size` `and min_period` paramters of the rolling() function.

Why is this and how can I get rid of the NaN value on the top right corner?

Comment: DataFrame.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None)[source]

Comment: @itprorh66 Could you please also explain your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another step:

```
X = X.fillna(X[40296].median(), axis 1, inplace=True)
```

I am using the median of the Column titled 40296, in this example, but you could use any value you deem appropriate.